# How to tag and categorize Life, the Universe, and Everything?

Tags: tags, hierarchy, taxonomy, categories

Jokes aside, I am trying to build a tag hierarchy for a library of icons that could contain potentially anything. The problem is how to make clear and simple hierarchy of (most) objects? I am not trying to make super specific categories, just to help users with searching (if I can narrow down 10k icons into categories of 100s that should be already a big help).

I started doing it myself from scratch but feel that making it right is very challenging. I am sure some studies were done already on this subject. Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[List of Dewey Decimal classes - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dewey_Decimal_classes)

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont want a hierarchy, but instead a collection of tags about each icon.  Then you can select only the icons which have all of the requested tags.

The real problem is the Parent/Child problem.  Do icons of children have parents, or do parents have children?  If you say parents have children, you double up the children in the hierarchy, because each of the children have to be under each of the parents.  The same is true if you view it the opposite way.  It is often better (particularly for what you are proposing) to just assign attributes to each "person" for who their children are and who their parents are.  Then you can let the user decide what the tree looks like.

Comment: I am currently have simple tags, but I usually end up with tagging many images with same "celebrity, female, human" or "red, ball, toy, object" which is just asking for a hierarchy. Or at least using plain tags would be good enough solution if I have some general tags that I can reuse (like human, male, object, etc).

Comment: @serg that is ok to have plenty of simple tags, once the user specifies 3 or 4 of them, the size of the returned set will be significantly narrowed as long as your icons not correlated around the same tag names.  I would imagine "red ball" would narrow down 10K icons to just a hand full of images unless your data is of icons from a sports and baby supply store

Answer (score 0):

Ask for people to add tags and a description to any icon then provides a search engine. They is no other way : nobody goes through 1000 categories to find a content anymore. If they see a big index page, they bounce and google the pic they are looking for.

Comment: Why not take best from the both worlds and put tags into hierarchy? You can still search by tags, but you can further refine your search if you want. If you searched for "human" offering further refinement as "male/female" isn't a bad idea, is it?

Comment: Depends of your public. Giving options is not user friendly. If your product is for teckies, go for it. If not, then two ways is already too much. People don't want to think about what they do, they want to do it. I'd, personally, prefer to be able to use both search and categories. But I'm not representative of the end use behavior. What do you think have the more success : the almost empty goole web page, or the crowded Yahoo index page ?